# Making a Spring Boot Standalone Web application which will run in desktop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am making a Restful API Web Application :-

- BackEnd :- Spring Boot
- FrontEnd :- Angular 2
- Database :- MySQL

Is it possible to package the app as a standalone Installer or maybe a single Jar file which can be run on clients Windows Machine and it will install all the required platforms like jre,apache tomcat,mysql,etc and create an icon which will open the app in the browser ?

If it is not possible then what are the possible alternatives from which we can achieve similar behavior.

Comment: I think it would be best not to use MySQL in that case. All the rest are pretty self-contained, but MySQL is usually a system service.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? 
I guess you could take a look into JavaFX.  
You will find some proof of concept if you google for JavaFX + Angular or Spring Boot.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ok then can you answer a solution considering alternative to MYSQL with steps to package that ?Also I want to mention the db is expected to be considerably high in size.

Comment: Frankly, I think you are going in the wrong direction entirely. If the application is for individual users, not one that contacts a central server, then although it's *possible* to build a local REST application and use the browser for the app, it's probably not the best implementation, and a GUI application will be better.

Comment: @RealSkeptic No not for single User.One user can install it on a machine and other users on the LAN should also be able to access the app typing the address in the url.

Comment: Then that should not be on a personal computer but on a server. And installed as a service. An individual's machine will most likely have a Firewall installed, and what happens when he goes home and shuts down his machine?

Comment: @RealSkeptic That will not be the case in my scenario. Consider a small setup ,say a Small Pharma shop having 5-10 computers in a single LAN. All the other PC's will only use the app if the main Server PC is ON .

Comment: It is not recommended though. Still if you want to you can do it using Electron Desktop package installer.
Reference to download the packager: https://github.com/electron/electron-packager It uses electron framework. To know the details: https://electronjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

A web application running in a client's windows machine is not the best scenario; but since you are open to alternatives, here is a possible alternative solution:

- [Dockerize](https://www.docker.com/) your web application
- Install docker on the client's machine
- Pull the docker image from a private docker registry or distribute your own image to the client
- Shortcut a command to run in the format "docker run OPTIONS IMAGE"; do not forget to expose your ports
- Open the browser and access the app.

I would never try this, please use a server instead...

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.Although I have never used docker before but sounds like a promising solution.I will try it .